# AngularJs - 'Page not found' after $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

Tags: angularjs, route-provider

Putting this in my .config method removes the # from the URL

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
     enabled: true,
     requireBase: false
});
```

In order to fix the manual refresh, i´ve seen many answers, buy all of them refer to changes in the server to handle requests. Is there a way of fixing the manual refresh issue purelly from the frontend? I' using $routeProvider in my application for managing routing.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you want to remove '#' ? Any particular reason ?

Comment: @pravs yes, i'm integrating with a third-party SDK that takes my URL and provides me another one with parametrs, but when the # is present, isn't working right. Unfortunately, i don't have a choice, I have to make my app work without the #

Comment: I had similar problem after using html5Mode , resolved it by restricting myself to angular 1.5.x and using #. I am looking towards a solution which will remove # from URL. will updated in a day

Comment: I'm using Angular 1.5.8, so if you find a solution, share it pls! :)

Answer (score 0):

No there is not another way.

When you remove the #! from the URL the server is going to try to fulfill that request, but it doesn't know anything about that part that would normally come after the #!.

The server side changes will make sure the server always responds with the base url to your angular application.  That way the browser doesn't refresh since it knows it already has that file loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Do you have 'base href' in your head tag? You can also reload route by using $route.reload() in your controller

Comment: with requireBase: false I don't need the base tag...in addition, I can´t access controllers since index is not being loaded. I think you didn't understand much the issue